# Swagger integer type cause an error Expected `string` for value, got `1`

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to describe body parameters, but got an error. Here is my `swagger.json` file:

```json
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Simple API overview",
    "version": "v2"
  },
  "host": "localhost:4000",
  "basePath": "/",
  "paths": {
    "/user/register": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "register",
        "summary": "User registration",
        "parameters": [{
          "in": "body",
          "name": "role",
          "required": true,
          "schema": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": 1
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to run it, I got an error:

```
Error: Expected `string` for value, got `1`
```

If I remove `example` field, I got this in Example Value section:

```
{}
```

Looks like the type definition is incorrect, but I couldn't figure out what's the difference between my code and examples from swagger docs.

Comment: Your request body definition is technically valid but doesn't make much sense. What is the request body supposed to look like? Is it supposed to be a JSON object like `{"role": 1, ...}`? Or form data `role=1&key=value&...`? Or something else?

Comment: Thanks for replying, @Helen, it should look like {"role": 1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason: there should be `consumes` field defined as `text/plain`. By default it is `application/json`.

The full code:

```json
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Simple API overview",
    "version": "v2"
  },
  "host": "localhost:4000",
  "basePath": "/",
  "paths": {
    "/user/register": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "register",
        "summary": "User registration",
        "consumes": ["text/plain"],
        "parameters": [{
          "in": "body",
          "name": "role",
          "required": true,
          "schema": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": 1
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this error is to change type from integer to string.

```
"parameters": [{
  "in": "body",
  "name": "role",
  "required": true,
  "schema": {
    "type": "string",
    "example": "1"
  }
}]
```